# next.js - Is there a better/more integrated way to call serverside code from client side than creating a /pages/api/myserversidecode.js and fetch it?

Tags: next.js

Is there a better/faster/more integrated way to call serverside code from client side than creating a /pages/api/myserversidecode.js and fetch it?

Im just wondering if Im missing something obvious.

Background:
I have a few lines of code that I want to execute on server. (The code contains some validation, calls out to other servers and there are some tokens not wanting to show). In next I've found that you can easily make api endpoints by placing code in /pages/api folder and this works fine. To call that code I then need to fetch/post to an endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js own examples heavily uses fetch("/api/...") so that might be the best way.

Example
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/auth0/lib/user.js

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

export async function fetchUser(cookie = '') {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.__user) {
    return window.__user
  }

  const res = await fetch(
    '/api/me',
    cookie
      ? {
          headers: {
            cookie,
          },
        }
      : {}
  )
```

`// code continues ...`